# How to fix broken layout in ie 9 - bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9

I am doing a website , using bootstrap 4. Unfortunately on ie9 layout is total broken. 
Is any way can I fix it? 
I've tried to change bootstrap 4 on bootstrap 3 but then I have big problems with navigation.

Answer (score 2):

IE9 is not supported in Bootstrap 4.

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/browsers-devices/#internet-explorer

Answer (score 2):

You could try *Bootstrap 4 for IE8 and IE9* https://coliff.github.io/bootstrap-ie8/

It should work for simple layouts.

*Note: IE9 is not officialy supported.*